# Activiti mysql performance tunning (indexes)

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, activiti, bpmn

**I have the slow query fired by activiti. What are the index that will help improving this queries performance ?:**

```
explain select distinct RES.*,
    VAR.ID_ as VAR_ID_, VAR.NAME_ as VAR_NAME_, VAR.VAR_TYPE_ as VAR_TYPE_, VAR.REV_ as VAR_REV_,
    VAR.PROC_INST_ID_ as VAR_PROC_INST_ID_, VAR.EXECUTION_ID_ as VAR_EXECUTION_ID_, VAR.TASK_ID_ as VAR_TASK_ID_,
    VAR.BYTEARRAY_ID_ as VAR_BYTEARRAY_ID_, VAR.DOUBLE_ as VAR_DOUBLE_, 
    VAR.TEXT_ as VAR_TEXT_, VAR.TEXT2_ as VAR_TEXT2_, VAR.LAST_UPDATED_TIME_ as VAR_LAST_UPDATED_TIME_, VAR.LONG_ as VAR_LONG_
    from ACT_HI_TASKINST RES
        left outer join 
        ACT_HI_VARINST VAR
         ON RES.ID_ = VAR.TASK_ID_ or RES.PROC_INST_ID_ = VAR.EXECUTION_ID_
      inner join 
      ACT_RE_PROCDEF D 
      on RES.PROC_DEF_ID_ = D.ID_ 
     inner join ACT_HI_VARINST A0 
     on RES.ID_ = A0.TASK_ID_ 
     WHERE  D.KEY_ = 'studentApprovalFlow'
        and RES.TASK_DEF_KEY_ = 'approve_student'
          and A0.NAME_= 'studentId'
          and A0.VAR_TYPE_ = 'string'
              and A0.TEXT_
    =
          'MT201083' 
     order by RES.ID_ desc, VAR.LAST_UPDATED_TIME_ asc 
    LIMIT 20000 OFFSET 0;
<br/>

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: D
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,ACT_UNIQ_PROCDEF
          key: ACT_UNIQ_PROCDEF
      key_len: 767
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: A0
         type: ref
possible_keys: ACT_IDX_HI_PROCVAR_NAME_TYPE
          key: ACT_IDX_HI_PROCVAR_NAME_TYPE
      key_len: 1070
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: RES
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 194
          ref: listman.A0.TASK_ID_
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: VAR
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 278238
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
-----------------------------
<br/>

It is taking 2 sec to return results.
Following are the indexes on the table:
mysql> show index in ACT_HI_VARINST \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Table: act_hi_varinst
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: PRIMARY
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: ID_
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 278238
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: 
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment: 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
        Table: act_hi_varinst
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: ACT_IDX_HI_PROCVAR_PROC_INST
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: PROC_INST_ID_
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 18549
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment: 
*************************** 3. row ***************************
        Table: act_hi_varinst
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: ACT_IDX_HI_PROCVAR_NAME_TYPE
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: NAME_
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 44
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: 
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment: 
*************************** 4. row ***************************
        Table: act_hi_varinst
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: ACT_IDX_HI_PROCVAR_NAME_TYPE
 Seq_in_index: 2
  Column_name: VAR_TYPE_
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 58
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment: 
<br/>
----------------------

mysql> show index in ACT_HI_TASKINST \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Table: act_hi_taskinst
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: PRIMARY
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: ID_
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 13061
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: 
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment: 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
        Table: act_hi_taskinst
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: PROC_INST_ID_
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: PROC_INST_ID_
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 13061
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment: 

<br/>
------------------------------

mysql> show index in ACT_RE_PROCDEF \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Table: act_re_procdef
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: PRIMARY
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: ID_
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 0
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: 
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment: 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
        Table: act_re_procdef
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: ACT_UNIQ_PROCDEF
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: KEY_
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 0
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: 
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment: 
*************************** 3. row ***************************
        Table: act_re_procdef
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: ACT_UNIQ_PROCDEF
 Seq_in_index: 2
  Column_name: VERSION_
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 0
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: 
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment: 
*************************** 4. row ***************************
        Table: act_re_procdef
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: ACT_UNIQ_PROCDEF
 Seq_in_index: 3
  Column_name: TENANT_ID_
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 0
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment:
```

---

Comment: NO! I predict noone will have a look at that code in depth, too much content, too badly formatted and it is unclear, what exactly you want. Furthermore you dont explain, what you have tried or what is currently happening.

Comment: I fixed the formatting.  Now, would you please provide a _formatted_ `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: @RickJames Activiti is an open source workflow framework: http://activiti.org/

Comment: Your database admin tools can tell you what indexes will help

Answer (score 1):

Create the simple or composite indexes on the columns referenced by the query in the order used.
First check if the index does not already exist.

`GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` also benefit a lot from a corresponding index.

in this example

```
WHERE  D.KEY_ = 'studentApprovalFlow' --> column already indexed

AND RES.TASK_DEF_KEY_ = 'approve_student'
```

--> missing index `HI_TASK_INST(TASK_DEF_KEY_)`

```
AND A0.NAME_= 'studentId'
AND A0.VAR_TYPE_ = 'string'
AND A0.TEXT_ = ' .. '
```

--> missing index `ACT_HI_VARINST(name, var_type, text)`

```
ORDER BY RES.ID_ desc, VAR.LAST_UPDATED_TIME_ asc
```

--> may be unable to use indexes because there are 2 tables referenced in `ORDER BY`;
try to create individual index for `LAST_UPDATED_TIME_ asc` to see if it improves the query.

Also put indexes in the foreign keys if they do not exist already.